# How to prevent multiple 'as const' on TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I prevent multiple 'as const' needing by declaring an interface or a type to solve this issue below?

```
export const MESSAGES = {
    WELlCOME_MESSAGE: 'Wellcome again' as const,
    UNALLOWED_MESSAGE: 'You are not allowed' as const,
    ALLOWED_MESSAGE: 'You are allowed' as const,
}
```

Comment: is you objective to prevent people editing the values?

Comment: @TheFabio I think OP simply wants to avoid repeatedly using `as const` for every single key-value pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just declare `as const` on the object level instead:

```
export const MESSAGES = {
    WELlCOME_MESSAGE: 'Wellcome again',
    UNALLOWED_MESSAGE: 'You are not allowed',
    ALLOWED_MESSAGE: 'You are allowed',
} as const;
```

[See example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLIFEDKOCCA4rnALxwDeAUHLXAOpYAyANgMIDy2A%20tnkVgBccAOT1gLFkgC2wOAEMA5vICWyEQBoadAKoA5fEyYdGAEV64CxYSICaEAK4Koc5BHjzJEAO7AAJpratIbGZhb81qL2TvIuCl6%20AVoAvgqoiCjoANxAA).

Comment: It works seamlessly, thank you, Terry.